# bordermatrix with thinner columns

Tags: bordermatrix

I'm trying to set-up the column width of a `bordermatrix` with the usual `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}` command (usual in the sense that it works for usual matrices) without success: what should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\quad` is used as seperator.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\let\quad\thinspace 
$\bordermatrix{%
   & 0 & 1 & 2 \cr
 0 & A & B & C \cr
 1 & d & e & f \cr
 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \cr
}$}

\end{document}
```