# Bordermatrix with thinner rows?

Tags: matrices, bordermatrix

I found this great question about how to [reduce white space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14389/bordermatrix-with-thinner-columns/14403#14403?newreg=a4e5e79a405243c78dc45f8224144cfa) in `bordermatrix` columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\let\quad\thinspace 
$\bordermatrix{%
   & 0 & 1 & 2 \cr
 0 & A & B & C \cr
 1 & d & e & f \cr
 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \cr
}$}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me how to produce that same effect for rows instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can always change `\baselinestretch`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}\begin{document}

{\let\quad\thinspace 
$\bordermatrix{%
   & 0 & 1 & 2 \cr
 0 & A & B & C \cr
 1 & d & e & f \cr
 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \cr
}$}

\end{document}
```